# Microsoft ActiveSync

Tags: ios, activesync

I am integrating microsoft activesync in my application using EAS Protocol. I have all code ready but now i am confused with WBXML request. Because of it i am getting Bad Request in response. So can you please guide me how can i convert my xml string to wbxml? I have already followed some instruction like [Exchange ActiveSync Objective-C Provision Command Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581327/exchange-activesync-objective-c-provision-command-bad-request) from different forums but not much helpful.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Search this site for WBXML and you'll find answers like these that should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693654/xml-to-wbxml-conversion-for-activesync-in-ios

Comment: @Dipen can you tell me, how to request the server any reference link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finally i found the answer. I used cocoa pods and libxml libraries as mentioned in http://cocoapods.org/?q=libwbxml